# Python "call()" function doesn't accept path to file from "abspath()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, window, python-3.4

Probably this question is obvious, so excuse me.

I want to execute shell command (Windows 8.1, Python 3.4) to open IE with SVG file.
I do it like this:

```
# imgpath = 'C:/Users/Vladimir/dot-code\\..\\graph1.svg'
tmp = FS.abspath(imgpath)
# tmp = 'C:\\Users\\Vladimir\\graph1.svg'
subprocess.call(["start", "", tmp])
```

Looks fine, but I get an exception inside call() - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] File not found.

I suppose the root of evil is double slashes in "tmp". How can I fix it?

Comment: Why your imgpath is different from your tmp path?

Comment: I generate images with GraphViz. Dot-code is in 'C:/Users/Vladimir/dot-code/graph1.dot'. I save generated images in previous directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass the empty string. (I guess, you meant to separate the command and argument.). Remove blank string. Just pass `start` and the path.

In addition to that `start` is not a real program, but a command builtin to `cmd`. Use `cmd /c`:

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'start', tmp])
```

or pass `shell=True` keyword argument:

```
subprocess.call(['start', tmp], shell=True)
```

BTW, on windows, you can use [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

```
import os
os.startfile(tmp)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. According to [docs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) first arg for start is "title".
But thanks for startfile!

Comment: @Vladimir, "title" is optional. If you specify only one argument that is interpreted as `filename`.

Comment: @Vladimir, If `subprocess.call` solution does not work, there two option: (1) using `shell=True`: `subprocess.call(['start', tmp], shell=True)`. (2) explicitly call `cmd.exe`: `subprocess.call(['cmd', '/c', 'start', tmp])`.  I just updated the answer to include this.

Comment: shell=True has fixed it! Thank you!